# How can I get out of two loops in Python, not only the inner one?

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-loops, break

When the answer is "Non", i need to get out of both if loops to continue with the program and i dont know how to do so, it only breaks from the inner one.

this is my first proyect and im idk much about python and im using the most basic functions(?? for everything so im definitely missing something very easy

this is my code, sorry for the french :(

```
plus = True

while plus:
    plusChiffres = input("Avez-vous besoin de plus de chiffres pour votre opération ? Écrivez \"Oui\" si vous en avez besoin. Si ce n'est pas nécessaire, écrivez \"Non, merci\" : ")

#plús et plús de chiffres
    if plusChiffres == "Oui":
        chiffreTrois = float(input("Seulement mettre le troiséme Chiffre !:"))
        while True:
            plusChiffresBLAGUE = input("Avez-vous besoin de PLUS de chiffres pour votre opération ? Écrivez \"Oui\" si vous en avez besoin. Si ce n'est pas nécessaire, écrivez \"Non, merci\" : ")
            if plusChiffresBLAGUE == "Oui":
                print("tu es ridicule! je ne vais met du plus chiffres a l'operation pour vous! c'est un petit et simple programme!")
                quit()

            elif plusChiffresBLAGUE == "Non, merci":
                print=("Oh merci mon ami ! Je n'avais pas l'intention de le faire de toute façon.")
                plus = False
```

I tried using break, after asking ai it told me to use the =false thing but it is not working either

Comment: Put everything into a function and `return`.

Comment: In your `elif` you need to add `break` in the end. `break` will get you out of the inner loop and since you set `plus = False` the outer loop will exit as well.

Answer (score 1):

when your required condition arise, put a flag as true and break the inner loop, and in the outerloop, just put a check about your flag, if true, then break the outer loop too.

```
plus = True

while plus:
    plusChiffres = input("Avez-vous besoin de plus de chiffres pour votre opération ? Écrivez \"Oui\" si vous en avez besoin. Si ce n'est pas nécessaire, écrivez \"Non, merci\" : ")

#plús et plús de chiffres
    if plusChiffres == "Oui":
        chiffreTrois = float(input("Seulement mettre le troiséme Chiffre !:"))
        while True:
            plusChiffresBLAGUE = input("Avez-vous besoin de PLUS de chiffres pour votre opération ? Écrivez \"Oui\" si vous en avez besoin. Si ce n'est pas nécessaire, écrivez \"Non, merci\" : ")
            if plusChiffresBLAGUE == "Oui":
                print("tu es ridicule! je ne vais met du plus chiffres a l'operation pour vous! c'est un petit et simple programme!")
                quit()

            elif plusChiffresBLAGUE == "Non, merci":
                print=("Oh merci mon ami ! Je n'avais pas l'intention de le faire de toute façon.")
                plus = False
                break
    if plus==False:
        break
```